# Azure Compute Emulator 2.0 is not starting

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I've upgraded to azure sdk 2.0, but now I can see the problem.
When I start compute emulator, i receive next error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: dfservice.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2.0.6493.1
  Problem Signature 03: 5168a32e
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa57ca
  Problem Signature 07: 464e
  Problem Signature 08: 15
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a8e6
  Additional Information 2: a8e684111f9925fc9aa99d4362da1f5b
  Additional Information 3: 6098
  Additional Information 4: 60983d56f9b30d0c938ef5a2e76b15c1
```

Debugging in Vs gave me next error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Illegal characters in path.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
       at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)
       at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
       at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Program.Main(String[] args)
  InnerException:
```

I've googled about "Illegal characters in path". There is advice to add environment variable `_CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY`. I've already had it and it points to `c:\csrunaz\`.

Uninstalling and re-installing didn't help.

Does anybody knows what to do, or at least how to see the path in  `CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was solved after reboot and reinstall of Compute Emulator.